# Stack creation gives error with Multiple layers reference with FindInMap

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

My lambda function has multiple layers. When I try to create cloud formation stack I get following error.

> #/Layers/0: expected type: String, found: JSONObject #/Layers/1: expected type: String, found: JSONObject

My cloud formation templates looks like below

```
Mappings:
 LayersInfo:
    dev:
      mylayer: 
        -  !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:layer:my-utils:1"
        -  !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:layer:my-db-layer:10"

MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    DependsOn: LambdaPolicy
    Properties:
      Description: xxxxx
      FunctionName: mylambda
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Layers: !FindInMap [LayersInfo, !Ref Region, mylayer]
```

Looks like it is not able to convert list to a string.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution

```
Mappings:
 LayersInfo:
  dev:
    mylayer1: "my-utils:1"
    mylayer2: "my-db-layer:10"

MyLambda:
 Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
 DependsOn: LambdaPolicy
 Properties:
  Description: xxxxx
  FunctionName: mylambda
  Handler: index.lambda_handler
  Layers: 
     -!Sub
      - arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:layer:${Layer1}
      - Layer1: FindInMap [LayersInfo, !Ref Region, mylayer1]
     -!Sub
      - arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:layer:${Layer2}
      - Layer2: FindInMap [LayersInfo, !Ref Region, mylayer2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Sub` in `Mappings`. Values in mapping must be explicit string or a list. So you have to hardcode `AWS::Region` and `AWS::AccountId` in your layers.

The alternative is to create your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to substitute actual values for region and accountid.

Comment: Thanks for telling limitations of Sub in Mapping. Please see the working solution below.